# 2D Array Manipulation (Replacing list elements)

Tags: python

I'm creating a program which outputs a 5x5 matrix of 0's. I then ask the user to input a number between 0-25 which will turn the selected element to a 1

I need the matrix output to show 0s, but really, behind the scenes it needs to be like this:
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25

For example: User inputs 7. The matrix will then output:

/output/
Please enter a number between 0-25:

0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0

What would be the easiest way to do this?

---

Current code:

```
def main():

    grid = [[0 for row in range(5)]for col in range(5)] #creates a 5x5 matrix

    #prints the matrix
    for row in grid: #for each row in the grid
        for column in row: #for each column in the row
            print(column,end="  ") #print a space at the end of the element
        print()

player1 = input("Please enter a number between 0-25: ")
main()
```

Comment: You can use `grid[int(player1) // 5][int(player1) % 5] = 1` but note that there are 26 numbers between 0 and 25, so it should either be `0-24` or `1-25`.

Comment: how would I get it to store each input once it changes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. The above will mutate `grid`, so every change will be stored.

Comment: I have managed to repeatedly ask and update the matrix inputs.
I've been playing around with your code and found that if I edit it to:
grid[int(player1) // 5][int(player1) % 5-1] = 1

It will print in the correct places, all bar multiples of 5 for some reason, they print out a line down.. would you know how to fix this?

Comment: I guess what you want is to subtract `1` from `player1`, not from the result of the modulo operator.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are looking for is [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html), which converts a flat index (0-24 in the 5x5 case) to a shaped index.
Also, note that a 5x5 matrix will contain 25 element ranged from 0-24, not 0-25.

Below is a piece of code demonstrating how you could do this. Also I have added a check for the user input so the number entered can only be an integer in the flat index range.

```
import numpy as np

sh = (5,5)
a = np.zeros(sh)
print(a)
while True:
    try:
        player1 = int(input('Number1: '))
        if player1 < 0 or player1 > a.size-1:
            raise ValueError # this will send it to the print message and back to the input option
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be in the range of 0-{}.".format(a.size))

a[np.unravel_index(player1,sh)] = 1
print(a)
```

This is the output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Number1: 7
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

**EDIT** (If you really need a list)

To use `numpy` operating on your list just convert the list to a `numpy.array`, use  `numpy.unravel_index` and convert it back to a list:

```
import numpy as np

sh = (5,5)
a_array = np.zeros(sh)
a_list = a_array.tolist() # Here numpy converts a to a list (your starting point)
a_array = np.array(a_list) # Here it converts it to a numpy.array
while True:
    try:
        player1 = int(input('Number1: '))
        if player1 < 0 or player1 > a_array.size-1:
            raise ValueError # this will send it to the print message and back to the input option
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be in the range of 0-{}.".format(a.size))
a_array[np.unravel_index(player1,sh)] = 1
a_list = a_array.tolist()
print(a_list)
```

You will get the same output but in a list form

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```